# What is the wrong withe code python

Tags: python

[image]When I am executing this code in http://www.pyschools.com/quiz/view_question/s2-q1. It gives error for both the answers... Please help
The questions is:

```
Write a function to convert temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit scale.
oC to oF Conversion: Multipy by 9, then divide by 5, then add 32.

Examples

    >>> Cel2Fah(28.0)
    '82.40'
    >>> Cel2Fah(0.00)
    '32.00'
```

## My Answer

```
 # Note: Return a string of 2 decimal places.
    def Cel2Fah(temp):
        x = 9.00
        y = 5.00
        z = 32.00
        a = temp * x
        a = a / y
        a = a + z
        return(a)
```

Comment: That link requires me to sign in and share my e-mail with the site, which I don't want to do. You should put the question here instead.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Post the errors!!!

Comment: This question strikes me as "why isn't pyschools.com working".  If you put your code into an actual Python interpreter, it works fine.

Comment: The code is functional (though uses more variables than necessary). If you can update your question with more specific information about the problem, we'll be able to help. Perhaps the problem is with the online system you are interacting with?

Comment: "Return a string of 2 decimal places." you are not returning a string

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak - Initial question was ambiguous as it was incomplete. It would be better if in the future you could make sure the question has all the info required. It could save atleast 15 people 5 minutes, that's 75 skilled minutes, I feel :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return this instead.

```
return '%.2f' %a
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything, I think.

Answer (score 7):

At the top it says:

```
# Note: Return a string of 2 decimal places.
```

You are not returning a string. You are returning a value of type `float`.

Since this looks like homework, I'll let you figure out how to fix this (hint: use the string formatting operator).

Comment: Whenever you say "I'll let you figure out how to fix this", six other people invariably post the answer. Is there an emoticon for ironic bitterness?

Answer (score 1):

change your return statement to read

```
return '%.2f' %a
```

Comment: already updated ... I was editing while the comments were coming in - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong syntactically with that code. It should work if you pass a number as parameter. It won't work if you pass anything but a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
def Cel2Fah(temp):
     cel=(round((((temp*9)/5) +32),2))
     return '%.2f' %cel
print Cel2Fah(36.9)
print Cel2Fah(29.0)
```

Comment: code-only answers are considered low quality, better add some explanation in English (what's `round` doing in there, for example)